# Rails 4: Scope not working in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, scopes

I'd like to order each forum by the number of forum posts in descending order. I have a `forum_posts_count` column already in place for my `Forum` table.

Forum.rb

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base

 scope :popular, -> { order("forum_posts_count DESC") }
 has_many :forum_posts, through: :forum_threads

end
```

forums_controller.rb

```
ForumsController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @forums = Forum.all.popular
 end
end
```

forum_post.rb
    Class ForumPost < ActiveRecord::Base

```
 has_one :forum, through: :forum_thread
 belongs_to :forum_thread, touch: true

  after_create :increment_forum_posts_count
  after_destroy :decrement_forum_posts_count

 private

  def increment_forum_posts_count       
    Forum.increment_counter( 'forum_posts_count', self.forum_thread.forum_id )
  end

  def decrement_forum_posts_count
    Forum.decrement_counter( 'forum_posts_count', self.forum_thread.forum_id )
  end

end
```

...add_counters_to_forums_table.rb (migration)

```
class AddCountersToForumsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration

 def self.up
  change_table :forums do |t|
   t.integer :forum_threads_count, :forum_posts_count, default: 0
 end

 Forum.reset_column_information

 Forum.all.pluck(:id).each do |id|
  Forum.reset_counters(id, :forum_posts)
  Forum.reset_counters(id, :forum_threads)
 end
end

def self.down
 change_table :forums do |t|
  t.remove :forum_threads_count, :forum_posts_count
 end
end

end
```

I'm not getting an error or anything, it's just not ordering the forums correctly. Could this be a problem with caching? I've reset the database and it's still incorrectly ordering.

Comment: what is the generated sql query? try `"forums.forum_posts_count DESC"`

Comment: Are you using `counter_cache` to maintain your `forum_posts_count` field? Does ForumPost have something like `belongs_to :forum, counter_cache: true`?

Comment: @Dan I'm not using `counter_cache` in the `ForumPost` model. I just updated the question and added the `forum_post.rb` file. Should I be using `counter_cache` or `touch` to `has_one :forum`?

Comment: @Kkulikovskis  `Started GET "/forums" for ::1 at 2016-06-08 15:01:19 -0700
Processing by ForumsController#index as HTML
  Forum Search (12.9ms)  curl http://localhost:9200/forums_development/_search?pretty -d '{"query":{"match_all":{}},"size":100000,"from":0,"suggest":{"text":"*","subject":{"phrase":{"field":"subject.suggest"}}},"fields":[]}'
  Rendered shared/_page_title.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Forum Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `forums`.* FROM `forums` WHERE `forums`.`id` IN (4, 5, 6, 2, 10, 3)`  Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: @BB123 You don't need to use `counter_cache` but it is pretty handy for keeping counts of related tables. Does your `forum_posts_count ` field have counts (integer numbers) in it? It would be helpful to see the SQL that is generated when you type `Forum.all.popular` into the Rails console. It seems like what you have should work.

Comment: Judging by what you pasted above it does not look like the scope is being applied. You should have seen `ORDER BY` towards the end of the `SELECT` statement. Does it work if you update the index method and replace `.popular` with `.order("forum_posts_count DESC")`?

Comment: @Dan - I typed in `Forum.all.popular` in the console and it ordered them correctly! But still nothing in the view. I just updated my question to show how I implemented `forum_posts_counter` into the `Forum` table.  I tried changing the index method and that did not work either. The sql query didn't even change. I am using fragment caching in the index view that encapsulates the counters. Would that have any issue with ordering?

Comment: @Dan would it help if you looked at my GitHub?